# multilingual web site using database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-2, globalization

I made a multilingual site using resource files (ASP.NET MVC 2). Now I want to use the database in order to make a page where the user can input the information that will be published on the site. Does this mean that I can no longer use resource files? On the way to keep multilingualism using database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try a custom resource provider. You can then choose what resources come from which sources.

The following urls might be of use:

- [Extending the ASP.NET 2.0
  Resource-Provider Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx)
- [Creating
  a Data Driven ASP.NET Localization
  Resource Provider and Editor](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwdbresourceprovider/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure if I get your question, but from a technical and practical point of view you can mix content coming from Resource files and content coming from a database.

For all you static texts (messages, buttons etc) you will use your resources, and for dynamic texts (texts that [often] change) you will use your database.

It is also possible to create your own resource provider, that instead of taking the resources out of a file, it will take it out of a database.

Comment: Thanks @WestDiscGolf, those are great resources for him/her to start with.

Answer (score 0):

For static content you can use resource files but if you need to modify data and you want to translate data in different languages you should use data base. using data base is more flexible.

Comment: Can you give me a reference where to go